# Debugging suddenly stopped in Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using Visual Studio Code for debugging PowerShell and everything was working as expected. All of a sudden I started seeing below two messages when I press F5 and debugging is stopped completely. I reinstalled PowerShell plugin but that did not work.

> Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly
>
> Timed out waiting for the PowerShell extension to start.

[image]

Edit: 7/27/18

My issue was resolved automatically last time. Yes, I did not do anything and it started working. Today issue reappear. I reinstalled VSC and Extention but none of that worked for me.

Another message started appearing

> Timed out waiting for the PowerShell extension to start.

Comment: I was seeing "System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path" error in the verbose log. And one of the folder in my solution folder has dot(.), everything started working once I removed it.

Comment: Strange. All I see is https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1113

Answer (score 0):

This is seen in the recent [PowerShell/vscode-powershell issue 1334](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1334) from a month ago.

> Can't execute scripts on debugger using `F5 - Start Debugging`.
> Even a simple one like this.

```
write-host "Test"
```

> Using the F8 shortcut it works.

The bug report is <del>being reviewed</del>.
Update august 2018: [PR 725](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellEditorServices/pull/725) will close the issue.

> There's a lot of race condition fixes in the PSRL changes, but that was mostly through adding locks.
> Those areas could probably benefit from similar refactorings, the locks were more like stop gaps.

It will be available in **[PowerShell/PowerShellEditorServices](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellEditorServices/releases) 1.8.4 or more**.

---

[Mapusoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2300185/mapusoft) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052467/debugging-suddenly-stopped-in-visual-studio-code/51054566?noredirect=1#comment124643097_51054566):

> In my case, the problem was a whole day, and it ended just when I removed all the watched expression from former inspections.
> As simple as `Remove All`, and all went magically to work again?

Comment: The debugger is not starting on F8 but surprisingly debugger started today. Trust me I haven't done anything to fix this :)

Comment: @RaviKhambhati Strange: maybe a process was blocked by a Windows handle, handle which no longer exists today?

Comment: When I faced this issue yday I restarted VSC followed by restarting my machine which did not fix this issue.

Comment: @RaviKhambhati does F5 start the debugger? or only F8?

Comment: F5 will start the debugger and F8 will run the command on the line where my cursor is

Comment: in my case the problem was a whole day, and it ended just when i removed all the watched expression from former inspections...as simple as Remove All, and all went magicly to work again

Comment: @Mapusoft Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.